Let $A$ and $B$ be classes. Show that: if $A \neq \emptyset$ then $A \cup (\bigcap B) =\bigcap\{A\cup b: b \in B\}$.
I have something but I'm sure that there is an easy way to proof this.
I still struggle to understand how to proof things like this in set theory. 
My attempt.
Let $x\in A \cup (\bigcap B)$ and $x\in U $ (x is a set)
then $(x \in A)$ or $(x \in \bigcap B)$ and $x\in U $
then $(x \in U$ and $ x\in A)$ or $(x \in U$ and $ x\in \bigcap B)$
then $(x \in U$ and $ x\in A)$ or $( x \in U $ and $\forall y \in B : x \in y)$
If $(x \in U$ and $ x\in A)$ happens then i can glue whatever class to $A$
then $(x \in A \cup b':b \in B)$
But here i don't know how to make the next step to get that $x \in \bigcap\{A\cup b: b \in B\}$.
Kind of the same happens when i take the other case $(x \in U $ and $\forall y \in B : x \in y)$.
And for $\bigcap\{A\cup b: b \in B\} \subseteq A \cup (\bigcap B)$.
Let $x \in \bigcap\{A\cup b: b \in B\}$
then by definition we get that $\forall y \in \{A\cup b: b \in B\} : x\in y$
Now let $a \in \{A\cup b: b \in B\}$ be arbitrary
then $A \cup a: a\in B : x \in a$
then $x \in A \cup a: a \in B$
And because we took $a$ arbitrary i guess we can say that $x\in A \cup (\bigcap B)$
And we defined $\bigcap A=\{x|\forall y \in A : x\in y\}$.
Could you help me giving me a hint or perhaps some book to get use to this kind of proof?\

As an FYI: MSE is not a "do my work for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, downvoted, & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.

Sorry, i didn't mean it, now i have showed what i tried.

You may drop $x\in U$ everywhere. Keep it implicit. If $x\in A$ then $\forall y\in B:x\in A\cup y$, i.e. $x \in \bigcap{A\cup b: b \in B}$. Same if $\forall y \in B : x \in y$.

Conversely if $x \in \bigcap{A\cup b: b \in B}$ then $\forall y\in B:x\in A\cup y$. If $x\in A$ we can conclude immediately $x\in A\cup(\bigcap B)$. If $x\notin A$ then $\forall y\in B:x\in (A\cup y)\setminus A$ hence $x\in\bigcap B$, so $x\in A\cup(\bigcap B)$ as well.

Everything after your "Now let $a \in {A\cup b: b \in B}$ be arbitrary" is nonsense. Your $a$ is equal to $A\cup b$ for some $b\in B$.

Thanks, I have some problems proving when a $\forall$ is involved.

Let us make the definition explicit: $\bigcap(B)=\lbrace y:\forall b\in B, y\in b\rbrace$. So we can write for any $x$:
$$\begin{aligned}
x\in A \cup\left(\bigcap B\right) &\iff x\in A \lor \left(\forall b\in B, x\in b\right)\\
&\iff \forall b\in B, \left(x\in A\lor x\in b\right)
\\&\iff \forall b\in B, x\in A\cup b
\\&\iff x\in\bigcap\left\lbrace A\cup b: b\in B\right\rbrace
\end{aligned}$$
Both sets have the same elements, hence they are equal: $A \cup\left(\bigcap B\right) = \bigcap\left\lbrace A\cup b: b\in B\right\rbrace$ QED
